# How to select a set of vertices from on .OBJ in THREE?

Tags: 3d, three.js

I have the following use case where a user defines a selected area and I need to know all of the vertices within that boundary box. I know that I can traverse all of the vertices in a linear format and check if it's contained within the polygon but that would be expensive.

Any better techniques for selecting a set of vertices within a boundary box in THREE?

Comment: You can store them in a spatial subdivision data structure, e.g. k-D tree / octree to reduce the query time complexity from linear to logarithmic.

Comment: Are there any good examples of this? Pros and cons of various trees, etc.? Thank you, @meowgoesthedog

Comment: Asking for examples / tutorials / sample implementations is off-topic. Octrees are easier to construct + modify while k-D trees are more  performant + memory efficient.